# How to wrap output text from multiline textbox (web control) with a pre-configured width?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, word-wrap

I have a problem with text wrapping in `TextBox` (`System.Web.UI.WebControls`).

I have a textbox with columns set to 65, text mode property set to `MultiLine` and wrap property set to `true`.

When I gather the message, which the user has typed in with `txtMessage.Text` as a string, the line breaks "`\r\n`" are only put in where it happens in the UI, and not after 65 chars.

**Is this possible to solve, whiteout writing my own wrapping code?**

Ex. code:

In some init method:

```
txtMessage.Columns  = 65;
txtMessage.TextMode = TextMode.MultiLine;
txtMessage.Wrap     = true;
```

... The user types in some text and <kbd>Submit</kbd> ....

In an extraction method:

```
string text = txtMessage.Text;
// ...
// Do something with the text ...
```

The text, as **typed**, is:

> 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"

during extraction the string **becomes**:

> "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\r\n01234567890123456789"

**since** the text window only **fits 100** chars in one line.

But the column is **set to 65**, so the **result should be**:

> "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234\r\n56789012345678901234567890123456789"

Comment: The "cols" attribute set on textarea only specifies its presentational width on the UI. Wrapping doesn't break lines. However, in HTML5 "hard" wrap can insert line-breaks.

Comment: So you are seeing an expected behavior.  If you want to see line breaks after every 65 chars you'll have to implement it yourself as @abhitalks suggested.

Comment: So it is not possible to do using webForms without writing my own wrapping code?

Comment: oki.. Thanks, then I just have to start writing code. I'm bug fixing an Winforms page, so can't use HTML or JS to fix it.

Comment: No you'll have to write this functionality. The Winforms (or ASP.Net) TextBox doesn't support this feature natively. Next time tag the question correctly. We've just got to know that you are referring to a WinForms app.

Comment: I just went back and re-confirmed. You could try the `wrap="hard"` attribute and check on the server. (HTML5 feature, may not work with all browsers). Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535152(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @abhitalks this user is talking about a Winforms application and not ASP.Net.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice. However, I am now confused by the Op's comments above where in one comment it is "webforms" and the very next comment is "winforms". The question itself is tagged "asp.net"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winforms `TextBox` control doesn't support the functionality you require natively. But, there are two solutions for you.

1. Remove all newline and line breaks. Then add line break and new line characters after every 65 (or whatever the length you'd like) characters just before saving the values to database.
2. Inherit `TextBox` class and write your own `User Control` to override the Text property to represent the functionality in point one above. In this way you could reuse this control (But, not sure that's a concern)

Hope this helped.